# Creating new space/desktop in OSX with applescript?

Tags: macos, applescript, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, spaces

Since OSX seems to lack a keyboard shortcut to create a new space/desktop, I'm wondering if this could be accomplished creating an applescript and binding that to a keyboard shortcut.

Looked a ton on google and couldn't find anything. Surprised no one has asked this before... seems like it would be something that lots of people would find very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the list of AppleScript Spaces routines I found online ::

```
--my get_spaces_enabled()
--my set_spaces_enabled(enable_spaces)
--my toggle_spaces_enabled()
--my get_spaces_rows()
--my set_spaces_rows(row_count)
--my get_spaces_columns()
--my set_spaces_columns(column_count)
--my get_spaces_count()
--my show_all_spaces()
--my get_spaces_application_bindings()
--my set_spaces_application_bindings(new_bindings)
--my collect_application_in_current_space(application_bundle_id)
--my set_spaces_application_binding_for_application(application_bundle_id, chosen_space)
--my get_space_binding_for_application(application_bundle_id)
--my choose_space_for_current_application()
--my choose_space_for_application(application_bundle_id)
--my remove_spaces_application_binding(application_bundle_id)
--my get_spaces_arrow_key_modifiers()
--my get_spaces_numbers_key_modifiers()
--my switch_to_space(space_number)
--my open_spaces_preferences()
--my display_spaces_not_enabled_error()

on get_spaces_enabled()
   tell application "System Events" to tell spaces preferences of expose preferences to return (get spaces enabled)
end get_spaces_enabled

on set_spaces_enabled(enable_spaces)
   tell application "System Events" to tell spaces preferences of expose preferences to set spaces enabled to enable_spaces
end set_spaces_enabled

on toggle_spaces_enabled()
   my set_spaces_enabled(not (my get_spaces_enabled()))
end toggle_spaces_enabled

on get_spaces_rows()
   tell application "System Events" to tell spaces preferences of expose preferences to return (get spaces rows)
end get_spaces_rows

on set_spaces_rows(row_count)
   tell application "System Events" to tell spaces preferences of expose preferences to set spaces rows to row_count
end set_spaces_rows

on get_spaces_columns()
   tell application "System Events" to tell spaces preferences of expose preferences to return (get spaces columns)
end get_spaces_columns

on set_spaces_columns(column_count)
   tell application "System Events" to tell spaces preferences of expose preferences to set spaces columns to column_count
end set_spaces_columns

on get_spaces_count()
   return ((my get_spaces_rows()) * (my get_spaces_columns()))
end get_spaces_count

on show_all_spaces()
   try
       tell application "Finder" to set spaces_app_path to (application file id "com.apple.spaceslauncher") as string
       do shell script "open " & quoted form of POSIX path of spaces_app_path
   end try
end show_all_spaces

on get_spaces_application_bindings()
   tell application "System Events" to tell spaces preferences of expose preferences to return (get application bindings)
end get_spaces_application_bindings

on set_spaces_application_bindings(new_bindings)
   tell application "System Events" to tell spaces preferences of expose preferences to set application bindings to new_bindings
end set_spaces_application_bindings

on collect_application_in_current_space(application_bundle_id)
   set application_bundle_id to my make_lowercase(application_bundle_id)
   set app_bindings to my get_spaces_application_bindings()
   my set_spaces_application_bindings((run script "{|" & application_bundle_id & "|:65544}") & app_bindings)
   my set_spaces_application_bindings(app_bindings)
end collect_application_in_current_space

on set_spaces_application_binding_for_application(application_bundle_id, chosen_space)
   set application_bundle_id to my make_lowercase(application_bundle_id)
   if chosen_space is in {0, "None"} then
       my remove_spaces_application_binding(application_bundle_id)
   else
       if chosen_space = "All" then set chosen_space to 65544
       my set_spaces_application_bindings((run script "{|" & application_bundle_id & "|: " & chosen_space & "}") & (my get_spaces_application_bindings()))
   end if
end set_spaces_application_binding_for_application

on get_space_binding_for_application(application_bundle_id)
   set application_bundle_id to my make_lowercase(application_bundle_id)
   set app_bindings to my get_spaces_application_bindings()
   try
       get app_bindings as string
   on error error_string
       set app_bindings to my string_to_list(text 13 thru -20 of error_string, ", ")
   end try
   repeat with i from 1 to (count app_bindings)
       if item i of app_bindings starts with ("|" & application_bundle_id & "|:") then return (item 2 of (my string_to_list(item i of app_bindings, ":"))) as number
   end repeat
   return 0
end get_space_binding_for_application

on choose_space_for_current_application()
   return my choose_space_for_application(bundle identifier of (info for (path to frontmost application)))
end choose_space_for_current_application

on choose_space_for_application(application_bundle_id)
   set application_bundle_id to my make_lowercase(application_bundle_id)
   if (not my get_spaces_enabled()) then if (not my display_spaces_not_enabled_error()) then return false
   try
       tell application "Finder" to set app_path to (application file id application_bundle_id) as string
       set app_name to short name of (info for (app_path as alias))
       set the_choices to {"None", "All"}
       repeat with i from 1 to (my get_spaces_count())
           set end of the_choices to i
       end repeat
       set default_space to my get_space_binding_for_application(application_bundle_id)
       if default_space = 0 then
           set default_space to "None"
       else if default_space = 65544 then
           set default_space to "All"
       end if
       set chosen_space to (choose from list the_choices default items {default_space} with title "Spaces Assigner" with prompt "Assign " & app_name & " to Space:" OK button name "Assign" without multiple selections allowed and empty selection allowed)
       if chosen_space = false then return false
       my set_spaces_application_binding_for_application(application_bundle_id, item 1 of chosen_space)
       return true
   on error e number n
       log "choose_space_for_application (" & application_bundle_id & ") Error (" & n & "): " & e
       return false
   end try
end choose_space_for_application

on remove_spaces_application_binding(application_bundle_id)
   set application_bundle_id to my make_lowercase(application_bundle_id)
   set app_bindings to my get_spaces_application_bindings()
   try
       get app_bindings as string
   on error error_string
       set app_bindings to my string_to_list(text 13 thru -20 of error_string, ", ")
   end try
   set new_bindings to {}
   repeat with i in app_bindings
       set i to contents of i
       if i does not start with "|" & application_bundle_id & "|:" then set end of new_bindings to i
   end repeat
   my set_spaces_application_bindings(run script "{" & (my list_to_string(new_bindings, ", ")) & "}")
end remove_spaces_application_binding

on get_spaces_arrow_key_modifiers()
   tell application "System Events" to tell spaces preferences of expose preferences to return (get key modifiers of (get properties of arrow key modifiers))
end get_spaces_arrow_key_modifiers

on get_spaces_numbers_key_modifiers()
   tell application "System Events" to tell spaces preferences of expose preferences to return (get key modifiers of (get properties of numbers key modifiers))
end get_spaces_numbers_key_modifiers

on switch_to_space(space_number)
   if not my gui_scripting_check() then return
   set key_modifiers to my get_spaces_numbers_key_modifiers()
   tell application "System Events"
       set key_modifier_list to {}
       if key_modifiers contains command then set end of key_modifier_list to "command down"
       if key_modifiers contains control then set end of key_modifier_list to "control down"
       if key_modifiers contains option then set end of key_modifier_list to "option down"
       if key_modifiers contains shift then set end of key_modifier_list to "shift down"
       set key_modifier_list to my list_to_string(key_modifier_list, ", ")
       if key_modifier_list ≠ "" then set key_modifier_list to " using {" & key_modifier_list & "}"
   end tell
   run script ("tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"" & space_number & "\"" & key_modifier_list)
end switch_to_space

on open_spaces_preferences()
   tell application "System Preferences"
       activate
       tell pane id "com.apple.preference.expose" to reveal anchor "Spaces"
   end tell
end open_spaces_preferences

on display_spaces_not_enabled_error()
   beep
   activate
   if ((button returned of (display dialog "Spaces is not enabled. Would You like to enable it now?" with title "Spaces Error" buttons {"Keep Disabled", "Enable"} default button 2 with icon 0)) = "Keep Disabled") then return false
   my set_spaces_enabled(true)
   return true
end display_spaces_not_enabled_error

on list_to_string(l, d)
   tell (a reference to my text item delimiters)
       set {o, contents} to {contents, d}
       set {l, contents} to {"" & l, o}
   end tell
   return l as Unicode text
end list_to_string

on string_to_list(s, d)
   tell (a reference to my text item delimiters)
       set {o, contents} to {contents, d}
       set {s, contents} to {s's text items, o}
   end tell
   return s
end string_to_list

on gui_scripting_check()
   tell application "System Events" to set gui_scripting_enabled to UI elements enabled
   if not gui_scripting_enabled then
       tell application "System Preferences"
           activate
           set current pane to pane "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
           display dialog "This application utilizes the built-in Graphic User Interface Scripting architecture of Mac OS X which is currently disabled." & return & return & "You can activate GUI Scripting by selecting the checkbox \"Enable access for assistive devices\" in the Universal Access preference pane." with icon 2 buttons {"OK"} default button 1
       end tell
   end if
   return gui_scripting_enabled
end gui_scripting_check

on make_lowercase(the_string)
   return do shell script "echo " & quoted form of the_string & " | /usr/bin/perl -pe 'use encoding utf8; s/(\\w)/\\L$1/gi'"
end make_lowercase
```

You can use these to make your code :)

Link to the routines site :: [MacScripter - Applescript Spaces Routine](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=23453)

Comment: This would have been awesome, but unfortunately "spaces" no longer exists in the more recent versions of OSX so these subroutines do not work.